# How to check if an object is the last object on NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

How can I check if an object in the last object on an `NSArray`?

I've tried:

```
if ([currentStore isEqual:[Stores lastObject]])
{
  //Code
}
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get the index of object in array and check if that is one less than to total count. If yes then it is the last object.

Comment: your code seems fine, please check manually in array objects

Comment: what kind of object is currentStore

Comment: current store is an array

Comment: @SanjanPiya currentStore in NSString inside an NSArray (getting it using ForIn)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik currentStore in NSString inside an NSArray (getting it using ForIn)

Comment: Please print here Stores array log

Comment: I don't see why that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
BOOL lastElement = false;
NSUInteger index = [stores indexOfObject:currentStore];
if (index != NSNotFound)
{
    lastElement = (index == [stores count] - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit modified try this:

```
 NSUInteger index = [stores indexOfObject:currentStore];
            if (index == ([stores count]-1))
            {
                NSLog(@"Yes its Last");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't override isEqual method, the base class implementation of NSObject::isEqual only check if both pointers points to the same address.

This excellent article http://nshipster.com/equality/ explain objc equality principles

The below sample logs - Testing Stores - works fine

```
@interface Stores : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;

- (instancetype) initWithName:(NSString*) name;

@end

@implementation Stores

- (instancetype) initWithName:(NSString*) name;
{
    _name = name;
    return self;
}


- (BOOL)isEqualToStores:(Stores*) Stores
{
    if (!Stores)
        return NO;

    if (![_name isEqualToString:Stores.name] )
        return NO;

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if (self == object)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    if (![object isKindOfClass:[Stores class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self isEqualToStores:(Stores *)object];
}

@end

-(void) testStores
{
    Stores* last = [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"5"];
    NSArray* arr = @[
                     [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"1"],
                     [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"2"],
                     [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"3"],
                     [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"4"],
                     [[Stores alloc] initWithName:@"5"]
                     //last
                    ];

    if ([last isEqual:[arr lastObject]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Testing Stores - works fine");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Testing Stores - opps!?1?!?");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an array of `NSString` objects, which does correctly override `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough detail in the question, but I think few notes are due.

1. An `NSArray` object can contain the same item **several times**, in different indexes, so many of the suggestions here won't work if the same object appears both somewhere in the middle AND as the last object. e.g.

```
      NSString *a = @"A";
      NSString *b = @"B";
      NSString *c = @"C";
      NSString *d = @"D";
      NSArray *arr = @[a,b,a,c,b,b,c,c,d,a,d,b,d];
```

Here `d` is both the last object in `arr` but it also appears in indexes 8 and 10.

So if you ask

```
if ([stores indexOfObject:currentStore] == (stores.count - 1))
```

You will get wrong answer - since `indexOfObject:` will return 8, while last index is 13.

2. the method `isEqual:` doesn't check for IDENTITY but for EQUALITY. different objects can be equal e.g.

```
    NSString *ab = @"AB";
    NSString *a = @"A";
    NSString *ab2 = [a stringByAppendingString:@"B"]];
```

now `[ab isEqual:ab2]` but `ab` is not the same object as `ab2`.

3. Your code is generally OK, and you should only replace the `isEqual:` with simple `==` operator to make it work as expected.

```
    if ([currentStore == [Stores lastObject]])
    {
      //Code
    }
```